# Formatting JQuery outputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got some `jQuery` that outputs text concerning products (Item title, URL).

I am looking for a way to display the output as a dropdown attached to the search bar, or as a table. I want it to display so that the title is seen by the user as a link to the URL.

A sample of the output can be seen below:

```
http://www.urbanoutfitters.com/urban/catalog/productdetail.jsp?id=36394526&category=M-VANS,Vans Tulare Denim Jacket,  
http://www.urbanoutfitters.com/urban/catalog/productdetail.jsp?id=36400869&category=M-VANS,Vans Rowley Snapback Hat,  
http://www.urbanoutfitters.com/urban/catalog/productdetail.jsp?id=36394344&category=M-VANS,Vans Nathan Fletcher Photo Tee
```

Right now this just displays as text on the page in this HTML. The "?" is replaced by the text output above.

```
<input type="text" name="search_text" placeholder="Enter search your key">

<span id=result>?</span>
```

The `JavaScript` is below:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
$(function() {
    $('a#calculate').bind('click', function() {
    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_autocomplete', {
        search_type: $('input[name="search_type"]').val(),
        search_text: $('input[name="search_text"]').val()
    }, function(data) {
        $("#result").text(data.result);
    });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Inject html markup instead of raw text?

Comment: ^ That is true actually, it may be formatted already you are just displaying it as text

Comment: Can you take a moment and show the exact HTML output you want to create from (at least one of) those responses that you've shown; otherwise people are trying to guess your requirements rather than simply helping you (and showing you how to fulfil your requirements).

Comment: I was mostly looking more for the concept than an exact implementation, anything that formatted the text as html would answer the question. So, the chosen way of styling didn't really matter as much as implementing some kind of styling that I could work from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
   $("#result").append($("<a></a>").attr("href",url).html(url));


  or 
   $("#result").append($("<a></a>").attr("href",url).text(url));
```

Comment: You also need to show some text in the `<a>` element, otherwise it won't be visible at all (depending on the CSS, obviously).

Comment: Currently, this is not changing anything, should I change the HTML as well?

Comment: *it does change stuff, it makes nothing display

Comment: I ended up using this to get the answer I wanted, thank you

Comment: Note, to future people, this answer works if one changes, url to data.result. (and then do alot of styling)

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no spaces in the url, you can `split()` the result and format accordingly.

```
var result = data.result.split(' ');
var url = '<a href="' + result[0] + '">';
var i;

for(i=1; i < result.length; i++){
    url += result[i];
    url += " ";
}
   /* Other Code */

$('#result').html(url);
```

Comment: where should  place the " var result...... " ": }  " code, anywhere that I put it seems to break the rest of the code?